# searching in varchar field without single quote

Tags: php, mysql, sqldatatypes

How could `varchar` field in `Mysql` table can accept values without `single quote` in `query where clause`

```
MRM_RA1_ID='".$_SESSION['EmployeeID']."' (Not working)
MRM_RA1_ID=".$_SESSION['EmployeeID']."  (Working)
```

`MRM_RA1_ID` is varchar field

I am not getting this behaviour.
`Mysql` version is `5.1`.

Can someone please explain me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Answer (score -1):

Because it is taking value of $_SESSION['EmployeeID']
Just take its value as variable value.
And if you want simple string then single quotes must be used.

VARCHAR_FIELD = $Variable

VARCHAR_FIELD = 'Any data'

Comment: session is array and EmployeeID is one of its key.

Comment: And in his case, it is taking value of session array where it's key is EmployeeID

Comment: in session value will be any 5 digit number

Comment: no problem with 5 digits or 10 digits (unless there is no restriction on database level likewise)

Comment: You have to use single quotes when you are passing string. And you don't have to use single quotes when passing variable value or lets say value of array's key. And you are passing value of session key where key is EmployeeID